# Verification Statements and Acceptance Criteria

Tags: agile

We are using verification statements which describe how the requirement should be tested. These statements are co located and associated with the requirement. How is this different than a set of acceptance criteria?

Answer (score 1):

The term Acceptance Criteria are usually associated with User Stories, from XP (an Agile methodology). User Stories are supposed to be from a user point of view ("Hey Bob, look at my watch. When I get a phone call, the caller ID pops up on my watch screen"). Therefor, Acceptance Criteria also from that user's point of view. For example, your Acceptance Criteria may specify that:

- The Name and Phone Number of the person calling scroll across the top.
- Calls without caller ID show up as "Unlisted Caller"
- After you answer the call, the words "On Call" are at the top of the screen.

User Stories and Acceptance criteria do not specify exactly what do to - this is by design. They put constraints on what should be done and let the team solve the problem as well as it can within those constraints. This differs from many other requirements specification techniques that detail exactly what is expected.